# End View Puzzle, Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog, logic, constraints, clpfd

I'm trying to write a solver for End View Puzzles, using CLPFD (for those who are unfamiliar, here's a simple description http://www.funwithpuzzles.com/2009/12/abcd-end-view-a1.html ). I'm working on the constraint that I'll apply to each row/column, and running into some trouble.

So I'm thinking it should look something like this:

```
% NxN board, numbers from 0 to M in the row, Left/Right are the clues
% corresponding to the row
endviews(N,M,List,Left,Right):- 
    length(List,M),
    domain(List,0,M),
    stop_repeats(List,M),
    left_value(List,M,Left),
    reverse(List,RList),
    left_value(RList,M,Right)
    .
```

So the first 3 steps are pretty straight forward: initialize the board, set a domain, and make sure that this row won't repeat numbers other than `0` (I've written the `stop_repeats/2` predicate). The problem I'm encountering is dealing with the `left_value/3` predicate; I'm not really sure how to proceed here, since most of the list is not constrained and I do not actually know the position of this first positive element. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `left_value` should be similar to `start` on my answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [`automaton/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#automaton/3) constraint can help here? You can construct a finite automaton that accepts (optional) zero followed by the first letter as indicated, then an arbitrary sequence of zero and letters.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down the puzzle specification. That seems less general than your description of it, then I hardcoded the constraints, using the mapping 0=empty,1=A,2=B,3=C.

```
/*  File:    abc_view.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: May 21 2012
    Purpose:
*/

:- module(abc_view, [abc_view/0]).
:- [library(clpfd), '~/prolog/lambda'].

abc_view :-
    maplist(\Ls^(length(Ls, 4), Ls ins 0..3), [R1,R2,R3,R4]),
    transpose([R1,R2,R3,R4], [C1,C2,C3,C4]),

    maplist(all_distinct, [R1,R2,R3,R4]),
    maplist(all_distinct, [C1,C2,C3,C4]),

    start(R2, 3),
    start(R3, 3),
    finish(R3, 2),

    start(C3, 1),
    finish(C2, 2),

    maplist(writeln, [R1,R2,R3,R4]).

finish(X, V) :-
    reverse(X, Y),
    start(Y, V).

start([0,Y|_], Y).
start([Y|_], Y).
```

test:

```
?- abc_view.
[2,0,1,3]
[0,3,2,1]
[3,1,0,2]
[1,2,3,0]
true ;
false.
```

I hope you can use it to solve your more general puzzle.