# EndView game on gnu Prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu, clpfd

Problem in general : we have map 8*8 and we have to fill the empty squares with number from 1 to 6.But in each column and raw number should be met only 1 time.Two squares in each row and column are left empty.Numbers from both sides,up and down show us the first number,that should appear(but it can appear after two empty squares).

So,now i have this code,which finally works on swi-prolog for 4*4 map.

```
:- module(ab, [ab/0]).
:- [library(clpfd)].

gen_row(Ls):-length(Ls, 4), Ls ins 0..3.

transpose(Ms, Ts) :-
    %must_be(list(list), Ms),
    (   Ms = [] -> Ts = []
    ;   Ms = [F|_],
        transpose(F, Ms, Ts)
    ).

transpose([], _, []).
transpose([_|Rs], Ms, [Ts|Tss]) :-
    lists_firsts_rests(Ms, Ts, Ms1),
    transpose(Rs, Ms1, Tss).

lists_firsts_rests([], [], []).
lists_firsts_rests([[F|Os]|Rest], [F|Fs], [Os|Oss]) :-
    lists_firsts_rests(Rest, Fs, Oss).

ab :-
Rows = [R1,R2,R3,R4],
maplist(gen_row, Rows),
transpose(Rows, [C1,C2,C3,C4]),

maplist(all_distinct, [R1,R2,R3,R4]),
maplist(all_distinct, [C1,C2,C3,C4]),

start(R2, 3),
start(R3, 3),
finish(R3, 2),

start(C3, 1),
finish(C2, 2),

maplist(writeln, [R1,R2,R3,R4]).

finish(X, V) :-
reverse(X, Y),
start(Y, V).

start([0,Y|_], Y).
start([Y|_], Y).
```

But,it doesn't support the problem with 2 empty places for bigger area,like 8*8 puzzle.Any hint's?

Comment: Oona, you should expect your questions will be downvoted and closed. StackOverflow has policies devoted to 'global' usefulness. You will have to solve your too much detailed problems alone...

Comment: fd_all_different is for *GNU Prolog*, use all_different in *SWI Prolog*

Comment: I got this,and i am writing on GNU Prolog,but it still doesn't work.I cant get the thing with two zeros aka empty spaces.In this case we can't use "assumption of uniqueness"

Comment: please post the *exact* puzzle definition, I'm lost now and don't know the problem you are speaking of...

Comment: I have added a difinition.Thank you very much,you are very helpfull.Sorry for messy programing and explanetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must get transpose/2 from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12789732/874024) and replace all_distinct/1 with fd_all_distinct/2.

Also, get writeln and replace write here `maplist(write, [R1,R2,R3,R4]).`

**edit** A simple solution would be to extend the 'encoding' of the finite domain, reserving **two** digits as blanks, instead of just the 0, and extending the logic already seen in answer posted to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12789732/874024).

For analogy I'll call third_end_view, and would be (in **Gnu** Prolog)

```
/*  File:    third_end_view_puzzle.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Oct  10 2012
    Purpose: help to solve extended Second End View puzzle
             https://stackoverflow.com/q/12797708/874024
*/

:- include(transpose) .

third_end_view_puzzle :-

    length(Rows, 8),
    maplist(gen_row(8), Rows),
    transpose(Rows, Cols),

    maplist(fd_all_different, Rows),
    maplist(fd_all_different, Cols),

    Rows = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8],
    Cols = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8],

    start(R1, 4),
    start(R2, 2),
    start(R3, 3),
    start(R4, 5),
    start(R5, 3),
    finish(R1, 6),
    finish(R2, 4),
    finish(R3, 2),
    finish(R5, 1),
    finish(R7, 2),


    start(C2, 3),
    start(C3, 4),
    start(C4, 3),
    start(C5, 5),
%   start(C6, 4),
    start(C7, 1),
%   finish(C1, 3),
%   finish(C2, 2),
    finish(C3, 5),
    finish(C4, 5),
    finish(C5, 6),
    finish(C6, 1),
    finish(C7, 4),

    maplist(fd_labeling, Rows),
    nl,
    maplist(out_row, Rows).

gen_row(N, Ls) :-
    length(Ls, N),
    fd_domain(Ls, 1, N).

out_row([]) :- nl.
out_row([H|T]) :-
    (H >= 7 -> write('-') ; write(H)),
    write(' '),
    out_row(T).

% constraint: Num is max third in that direction
start(Vars, Num) :-
    Vars = [A,B,C|_],
    A #= Num #\/ (A #>= 7 #/\ B #= Num) #\/ (A #>= 7 #/\ B #>= 7 #/\ C #= Num).

finish(Var, Num) :-
    reverse(Var, Rev), start(Rev, Num).
```

I have used a simpler condition, without reification, to state the 'third view from direction'.

As previously, you see that some constraint (those commented out) make the puzzle unsolvable.

test:

```
| ?- third_end_view_puzzle.  

4 3 - - 5 2 1 6 
2 1 - 3 - 5 6 4 
3 5 4 1 - 6 2 - 
5 4 6 2 1 3 - - 
- - 3 6 2 4 5 1 
1 6 2 4 3 - - 5 
6 - 1 5 4 - 3 2 
- 2 5 - 6 1 4 3 

true ?
```

Comment: But what about 2 empty places,which i'll have at endView on 8*8?

Comment: Edit your question with the *exact* problem statement, then I'll show you the solution. But you should show us your efforts so far...

Comment: Thaks,i have edited question and now keep on working with it.

Comment: Thank you!That clears everything!You helped really much!